# How do I retrieve blob (containing serialized java object) from DB and convert them to xml?

Tags: java, xml, blob

I have some Java objects stored in an Oracle database. I wish to know the structure and content of the objects. So, I want to retrieve the blob and convert them to xml/any other displayable form.

Is this possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

I would extract the binary object from the database, create back the java object in memory (so you can also ensure the data is valid) and after that I would use a library like [**Protostuff**](https://code.google.com/p/protostuff/wiki/XmlSerialization) to quickly serialize the object in XML.

The advantage of using Protostuff is that you don't need anything but the java object. The object "schema" is calculated at runtime if needed.

Consider also that Protostuff supports a lot of different formats, like JSON, Protobuffer, YAML, etc...